# How to use IF with ISNA to avoid getting #N/A in VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel workbook with 20 sheets.The values of column D in each sheet is either blank or serial numbers, plus there is a heading too (D2). I want to get the last serial number in D of the previous sheet to be displayed in each sheet.
I use VLOOKUP function to find out the last serial number in column D in each previous sheet.

This formula works fine if column D of the previous sheet is not empty. But if it is blank, it shows #N/A again, which is not desirable.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet4!D:D,1))=TRUE,VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet3!D:D,1),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet3!D:D,1))=TRUE,VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet2!D:D,1),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet2!D:D,1))=TRUE,VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet1!D:D,1),0)))
```

If column D of sheet 4 is blank, the formula needs to check whether that of sheet 3 is empty and so on.
The above formula was entered in sheet 5.

Comment: What about wrapping the formula with `=IFERROR(...`?

Comment: Will #N/A be considered in iferror?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: There is an issue with the formula,  as you check first cell and provide the result without knowing if the result is an error as well.

Comment: That's true. But how to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the formula, as you check first cell and provide the result without knowing if the result is an error as well. You may take advantage of the formula IFERROR() and do the following:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet4!D:D,1),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet3!D:D,1),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet3!D:D,1),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet2!D:D,1),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet2!D:D,1),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,Sheet1!D:D,1),0))))),0)
```